# How to rollback Spring Transaction when an Exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, spring-transactions

I am using spring 3.0.5 and hibernate 3.6. In my project there is a scenario where i have to rollback transaction of any exception in thrown or error occurs.  This the sample code, Everything works fine  except transaction is not getting rolled back when I throw an Exception but if any exception is thrown such as **mysql.IntegrityConstraintException**   then transaction gets rolled back, why this is not happening in my case?

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>
    </bean>
      <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

        </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.alw.imps"/>
    <property name="configLocation">    
        <value>
            classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
     </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="stateDao" class="com.alw.imps.dao.StateDaoImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


        <bean id="stateService" class="com.alw.imps.services.StateService">
       <property name="stateDao" ref="stateDao"></property>
       <property name="cityDao" ref="cityDao"></property>
       <property name="customerDao" ref="customerDao"></property>
       </bean>  

        <bean id="customerDao" class="com.alw.imps.dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
       </bean> 

            <bean id="cityDao" class="com.alw.imps.dao.CityDaoImpl">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
            </bean>  





<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>        

<tx:advice id = "txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
<tx:attributes>
<tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
</tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

**Service class StateService**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public class StateService {

  private StateDaoImpl stateDao;
  private CityDao cityDao;
  private CustomerDao customerDao;

  public void setCustomerDao(CustomerDao customerDao) {
    this.customerDao = customerDao;
  }

  public void setStateDao(StateDaoImpl stateDao) {
    this.stateDao = stateDao;
  }

  public CityDao getCityDao() {
    return cityDao;
  }

  public void setCityDao(CityDao cityDao) {
    this.cityDao = cityDao;
  }

  public void addState() {
    try {
      State state=new State();
      state.setStateName("Delhi");
      stateDao.create(state);
      addCity();
      addCustomer();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void addCity() throws Exception {
    City city=new City();
    city.setCiytName("Delhi");
    city.setStateId(1);
    cityDao.create(city);
  }

  public void addCustomer() throws Exception {
    throw new java.lang.Exception();
  }
```

**DAO**

```
public class StateDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<State, Integer> implements StateDao {
}
```

**GenericDaoImpl**

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T,PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T,PK> {
  public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  public Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  public PK create(T o) {
    Session ss= getSession();
    ss.save(o);
    return null;
  }
```

**hibernate.cfg**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit">false</property>
    <mapping class="com.alw.imps.pojo.State"/>
    <mapping class="com.alw.imps.pojo.City"/> 
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

So as I said my problem is transaction is not getting rollback when i throw an exception of type **Exception** from method **addCustomer()**

Comment: So far everything looks fine and it should be rolling back the transaction.  Is there a possibility that the transaction could be starting higher up the call stack.  Maybe if you add the spring config where you configure the transactions it would help.

Comment: I don't believe your `MyService` class is getting proxied at all. The rollback you are seeing is coming from the db, not from the transaction.

Comment: Please post your configuration and your call stack with method signatures/annotations so we can better evaluate the situation.

Comment: @Moles-JWS i have added the configuration and other dependencies,please check the update

Comment: What method are you calling from the outside of the service? addCustomer() doesn't do anything other than throwing an exception. Do you call addState(), in reality?

Comment: @JBNizet yes, I am calling addState() from a main method ,please check the update part.

Comment: if there is an IntegrityConstraintsException of mysql then transaction is successfully rollback but when i throw an Exception of type Exception then transaction is not getting rollbacked

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your transaction is not rollbacked because there is no exception thrown: the `addState()` method that you call catches the exception:

```
public void addState() {
    try {
        State state=new State();
        state.setStateName("Delhi");
        stateDao.create(state);
        addCity();
        addCustomer();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the transactional Spring proxy doesn't see any exception thrown and doesn't rollback the transaction.

It works for exceptions thrown from the DAO because the DAO is itself transactional, so its own transactional proxy detects the exception being thrown by the DAO and marks the transaction for rollback. The exception is then propagated to the service and caught by your code, but the transaction is already marked for rollback at this point.

Comment: thanks jb , It was my fault...it was a silly mistake and cant be acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

Your transaction is not getting rolled back because you are not letting Exception to reach to Spring framework, you are catching the exception in your code itself.
So instead of

```
public void addState() 
{
        try
        {
        State state=new State();
        state.setStateName("Delhi");
        stateDao.create(state);
        addCity();
        addCustomer();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

use

```
public void addState() 
{
        State state=new State();
        state.setStateName("Delhi");
        stateDao.create(state);
        addCity();
        addCustomer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The transaction has not been rolled back, because you are catching the exception yourself, by writing catch block..

This can be done in normal cases, but in spring transaction, if you do so, how does spring transaction manager knows the exception is happening.. thats why it is not getting rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You can find answers to most questions in Spring API doc. 
`@Transactional` has a field `Class<? extends Throwable>[] rollbackFor()`:

> By default, a transaction will be rolling back on `RuntimeException` and
>   `Error` but not on checked exceptions (business exceptions).See `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(Throwable)` for a detailed explanation.

Meaning that, for the following cases, no matter how the caller deal with exceptions, only the first `RunTimeException` case would call roleback by default.

```
// Only this case would roll back by default
@Override
@Transactional
public void testRollbackRuntimeException() {
    // jpa operation.
    throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
}

// never roll back, because its caught.
@Override
@Transactional
public void testRollbackRuntimeExceptionCaught() {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}

// @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) would also rollback. but by default no
@Override
@Transactional
public void  testRollBackWithExceptionCaught() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("test exception");
}

// never roll back because the checked exception is caught.
@Override
@Transactional
public void  testRollBackWithExceptionCaught() {
    try {
        throw new Exception("test exception");
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

And mostly you may want to roll back for checked exceptions undistinguishedly, using
`@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`